# Machine Learning - Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)

Tags: machine-learning

Gostaria de saber como funciona o modelo probabilístico de tópicos,  **Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)**:

- Quais aplicações ele tem?
- Exemplo da implementação em uma linguagem de programação?